# How to have function call on the datatable editor save/edit/delete window submit buttons.?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, editor

Please find the free data editor plugin demo 
http://jsfiddle.net/rmcmaster/bbLjzspf/22/

I want to have a function call on **Save/Delete/Update** button to send the changes to the database. Please suggest a way or an alternative for this.

Thank you in advance`enter code here`

Comment: Use `AJAX` to send the data to whatever server-side language you are using to add/edit items from/on the database.... I think more research will be required for you to accomplish this. A solid answer cannot be given without understanding your database structure or what language you are using for the back-end/server .

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response. But where could I found the Save/Edit/Delete button HTML to insert my ajax function in it? My Requirement is simple as I Just need to know where to have a function call method for those Save/Edit/Delete buttons which is present on the hover window. Please have a look on the demo to get my point and suggest me

Comment: In the JsFiddle you have provided, scroll down to the bottom of the `javascript` section. You will see `myTable = $('#example').DataTable({` The buttons are added there.

Comment: Yes I do see that. It is for Add/Edit/Delete button that shows on the top of window. I need to know where to write the function call for the Add Record/Save Changes/Delete Record buttons which comes on the hover window when we press those Add/Edit/Delete button respectively.

Comment: Maybe reading up on more examples will help?  [**datatables.net/examples**](https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/null_data_source.html)

Comment: if you want to have a function to call after clicking one of the buttons, refer to this reference https://editor.datatables.net/manual/events